# Send data from XAMPP(MYSQL) to android

Tags: android, xampp

I wanted a background service that listens for data from XAMPP server. I don't want the app to make  HTTP requests to check data in the server periodically, instead i want to have an event  in the app that gets invoked along the data from the server. This question may seem vague but can anyone suggest me from where to start?? I will be very thankful.

Comment: Take a look at [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/). This will allow your webserver to contact your android device at any moment in time.

Comment: thanks..i'll refer to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Node.js with express and socket.io, its easy to install and for usage. But also you can use online socket services. And for MySQL querys you can use Sequelize.